# Hide divs based on number of check boxes checked with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I want to hid divs based on number of check boxes checked. Div A is visible on page load while div B is hidden. If total number of checkboxes checked is equal 2 or great than 2 than i want to hide div A and show div B.

```
 <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20"/> A 
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6"/>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7"/>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7"/> 
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7"/> 
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7"/> 

        <div class="a"> Hello </div>
        <div class="b" style="display:none"> BYE </div>

  Total checked boxes= <span id="result"></span>
```

Have constantly failed to achieve this. Currently i am able to count the total checked boxes but unable to find a way to use the total count to show and hide divs.

```
      function showChecked(){
        var length = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length,
        text = "Total Number of Items Selected = "

    document.getElementById("result").textContent = length;
        document.getElementById("final").value = length;
}
 document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(i=>{
  i.onclick = function(){
  showChecked();
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question and include what you have tried so far please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click event listener to each of the checkboxes to increment a counter variable and if the counter is more than or equal to 2, set the display property of the `.a` div to `none` and the `.b` div to `block`.

You can use a querySelector to get all of your checkboxes if you give them all the same name (like "E33"):

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=E33]");
```

To get all checked checkboxes with the name "E33", use the `:checked` selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=E33]:checked").length;
```

```html
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20"/> A 
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="6"/>
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="7"/>
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="7"/> 
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="7"/> 
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="7"/> 

<div class="a" id="a"> Hello </div>
<div class="b" style="display:none" id="b"> BYE </div>
<script>
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[ name=E33]:checked").length;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=E33]");
for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(this.checked){
      checked++;
      if(checked>=2){
        a.style.display = "none";
        b.style.display = "block";
      } 
    } else {
       checked--;
      if(checked<2){
        a.style.display = "block";
        b.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

If you want to select your checkboxes by class:

```html
<input class="input" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20"/> A 
<input class="input" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6"/>
<input class="input" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7"/>
<input class="input" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7"/> 
<input class="input" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7"/> 
<input class="input" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7"/> 

    <div class="a" id="a"> Hello </div>
    <div class="b" style="display:none" id="b"> BYE </div>
    <script>
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var b = document.getElementById('b');
    var checked = document.querySelectorAll("input.input:checked").length;
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input.input");
    for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
      checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if(this.checked){
          checked++;
          if(checked>=2){
            a.style.display = "none";
            b.style.display = "block";
          } 
        } else {
           checked--;
          if(checked<2){
            a.style.display = "block";
            b.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: unfortunately cannot give same name to all checkboxes.I can only give same class to all checkboxes. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: @Sali No problem.

Answer (score 0):

A function to scan all of your elements would be the easiest way.

In this example, I have created a function named *getAmountChecked* which scans all checkboxes with the class 'iput'. This then calculates how many there were, how many are checked and how many aren't checked; I like to have access to any important info when I check things like this. This comes in the form of an object with the values *totalItems*, *totalChecked* and *totalUnchecked*.

My function *verifyInputs* calls *getAmountChecked* and uses the value of *totalChecked* to determine which elements to show/hide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
        function getAmountChecked(className) {
            var registeredInputs = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
            var totalChecked = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < registeredInputs.length; i++) {
                totalChecked+=registeredInputs[i].checked==true;
            }
            return {totalItems: registeredInputs.length, totalChecked:totalChecked, totalUnchecked: registeredInputs.length-totalChecked};
        }
        function verifyInputs(className) {
            var checkCount = getAmountChecked(className);
            document.getElementById('a').style.display = checkCount.totalChecked < 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.getElementById('b').style.display = checkCount.totalChecked >= 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input class="iput" onclick="verifyInputs('iput')" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20"/>
        <input class="iput" onclick="verifyInputs('iput')" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6"/>
        <input class="iput" onclick="verifyInputs('iput')" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7"/>
        <input class="iput" onclick="verifyInputs('iput')" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7"/> 
        <input class="iput" onclick="verifyInputs('iput')" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7"/> 
        <input class="iput" onclick="verifyInputs('iput')" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7"/> 

        <div class="a" id="a"> Hello </div>
        <div class="b" id="b" style="display:none"> BYE </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is, with caveats, possible entirely in CSS:

```
/* styling the <div> element with a class of "a",
   the 'default' state and the state in which
   one of the <input> elements are checked: */
div.a,
input:checked~div.a {
  display: block;
}

/* styling the <div> element with the class of 'b',
   and also the <div> element with the class of 'a'
   when it's preceded by two <input> elements that
   are checked: */
div.b,
input:checked~input:checked~div.a {
  display: none;
}

/* finally we show the <div> with a class of 'b'
   when it's preceded by two <input> elements
   both of which are checked: */
input:checked~input:checked~div.b {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
div.a,
input:checked~div.a {
  display: block;
}

div.b,
input:checked~input:checked~div.a {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~input:checked~div.b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" />

<div class="a"> Hello </div>
<div class="b"> BYE </div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lpbyh2n6/).

With the CSS above I've used the tilde (`~`) operator, the general-sibling combinator; this selects a following sibling element. The selector:

```
`input:checked ~ input:checked ~ div.b`
```

will match `div.b` if two, or more, `<input>` elements are checked.

This approach works. But, on to the caveats: if there are multiple groups of radio-buttons each group followed by the `<div>` elements, checking `<input>` elements in the first group – by virtue of the `~` combinator – will also select, and style, the `<div>` elements in the second group:

```css
div.a,
input:checked~div.a {
  display: block;
}

div.b,
input:checked~input:checked~div.a {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~input:checked~div.b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" />

<div class="a"> Hello </div>
<div class="b"> BYE </div>

<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" />

<div class="a"> Hello </div>
<div class="b"> BYE </div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lpbyh2n6/1/).

To prevent this each of the 'groups' must be wrapped in an element to prevent the general-sibling combinator from matching elements in subsequent groups:

```css
div.a,
input:checked~div.a {
  display: block;
}

div.b,
input:checked~input:checked~div.a {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~input:checked~div.b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" />

  <div class="a"> Hello </div>
  <div class="b"> BYE </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" />
  <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" />

  <div class="a"> Hello </div>
  <div class="b"> BYE </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lpbyh2n6/2/).

Further, a common UI approach for `<input>` elements is to wrap them in a `<label>` element in order for a click on the text/content of the `<label>` to check/uncheck the check-box.

If these check-boxes are wrapped in a `<label>` then, predictably, the general-sibling combinator will be unable to select the `<div>` elements based on the state of the `<input>` elements (see: "[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/82548)"). `<label>` elements can, of course, appear as siblings (or any other relationship) to the `<input>` elements; although this requires that each `<input>` with a `<label>` in the document must have an `id` property in order for an association to be formed:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
}

div.a,
input:checked~div.a {
  display: block;
}

div.b,
input:checked~input:checked~div.a {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~input:checked~div.b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>All the labels</legend>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>One</legend>
      <label for="a">a</label>
      <label for="b">b</label>
      <label for="c">c</label>
      <label for="d">d</label>
      <label for="e">e</label>
      <label for="f">f</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Two</legend>
      <label for="g">g</label>
      <label for="h">h</label>
      <label for="i">i</label>
      <label for="j">j</label>
      <label for="k">k</label>
      <label for="l">l</label>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" id="a">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" id="b">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" id="c">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" id="d">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" id="e">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" id="f">

    <div class="a"> Hello </div>
    <div class="b"> BYE </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" id="g">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" id="h">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" id="i">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" id="j">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" id="k">
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" id="l">

    <div class="a"> Hello </div>
    <div class="b"> BYE </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lpbyh2n6/3/).

More sensibly, and to allow styling of those `<label>` elements to reflect the styling of the checked/unchecked nature of the `<input>` elements they would follow the elements (although it's perfectly valid to associate one `<input>` with multiple `<label>` elements, and in this demo I'm leaving the badly-placed original group in place to demonstrate that multiple `<label>` elements associated with a single `<input>` works):

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
}

/* styling the <label> adjacent to an <input>: */
input+label {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* styling the <label> adjacent to a checked <input>: */
input:checked+label {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

div.a,
input:checked~div.a {
  display: block;
}

div.b,
input:checked~input:checked~div.a {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~input:checked~div.b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>All the labels</legend>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>One</legend>
      <label for="a">a</label>
      <label for="b">b</label>
      <label for="c">c</label>
      <label for="d">d</label>
      <label for="e">e</label>
      <label for="f">f</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Two</legend>
      <label for="g">g</label>
      <label for="h">h</label>
      <label for="i">i</label>
      <label for="j">j</label>
      <label for="k">k</label>
      <label for="l">l</label>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" id="a"><label for="a">a</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" id="b"><label for="b">b</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" id="c"><label for="c">c</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" id="d"><label for="d">d</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" id="e"><label for="e">e</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" id="f"><label for="f">f</label>

    <div class="a"> Hello </div>
    <div class="b"> BYE </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20" id="g"><label for="g">g</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6" id="h"><label for="h">h</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E646" value="33" stock="7" id="i"><label for="i">i</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E46" value="33" stock="7" id="j"><label for="j">j</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E626" value="33" stock="7" id="k"><label for="k">k</label>
    <input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E656" value="33" stock="7" id="l"><label for="l">l</label>

    <div class="a"> Hello </div>
    <div class="b"> BYE </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lpbyh2n6/4/).

References:

- Combinators:

  - [Adjacent-sibling (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).
  - [General-sibling (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).
- [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).